# Where can I find good research on long term health impact of different types/brands of infant formula (in the US)?

Tags: infant, formula, bottle-feeding

My wife can no longer nurse our infant due to her health issues. Is there an online resource I can use to research different types/brands of infant formula? I'm looking for independent, and preferable long-term longitudinal studies of child health similar to the ones which compare formula feeding vs breastfeeding. Do such studies exist? Where can we find them?

Comment: Any particular country?  In the UK the law is pretty strict and they're all fairly similar.

Comment: @DanBeale in the US

Comment: Might find some useful info here: http://www.fda.gov/Food/FoodSafety/Product-SpecificInformation/InfantFormula/ConsumerInformationAboutInfantFormula/ucm108079.htm

Comment: @DanBeale: US laws regarding formula are pretty strict too.

Comment: OPINION: You're unlikely to get an answer.  Any studies will compare formula with breast feeding, rather than formula with formula.  I think that there's not going to be any good quality (certainly no double blind, controlled, randomised) trials of various types of formulas.  My opinion is that you pick a brand name you trust (or at least one that you're not boycotting) and go with that.  Sorry this is not an answer.

Comment: It is clear that you are looking for studies which compare different formulas, but what is the question you are trying to answer / effect you wish to compare? cost? ingredients? overall impact on health or weight gain? corporate ethics?

Comment: @DanBeale I doubt any studies comparing breast to formula are randomized & controlled. In any case it wouldn't be a stretch if the correlational studies that existed differentiated between different types of formula -- milk based, soy based, etc.

Comment: @David, I'm strictly concerned with health. Edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Google Scholar is a good place to find references to the primary scientific literature, eg. see the results of a search [comparison of infant formula](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=comparison+of+infant+formula&btnG=Search&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C14).

I was surprised to find that [Consumer Reports has no articles comparing formulas](http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/search.htm?query=infant+formula), although there were a few discussing melamine and BPA in formulas.